# "`ascii‘ codec can’t enforce character u’\u2022‘ in position 206: ordinal not in range (128)"

Tags: python, server, ascii, ubuntu-20.04, python-unicode

I get this error when I try to execute my Python script on my Ubuntu 20.4 home server:

> `ascii‘ codec can’t enforce character u’\u2022‘ in position 206:
> ordinal not in range (128)

Comment: it would help if you could share your code with us

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9942594/16136190) help?

Comment: "enforce"? Really? Please copy'n'paste the error. Also, search for the error message, errors like this come up daily. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)", [mcve] and all their linked pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the Python Unicode [HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/unicode.html). This error is the [first example](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type).

Basically, you shouldn't `str` to convert from Unicode to encoded text/bytes.

Instead, use `.encode()` to encode the string:

```
text = 'some_str'.encode('utf-8').strip()
```